# PHP preg_match not giving me the expected result

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have to check if a string matches bio control numbers for products. [This link](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96ko-Kontrollstelle) has the specifications (unfortunatly in german).

The numbers start with a country-code, followed by 3 characters and two or three digits. Here some examples:

```
DE-ÖKO-233
IT-BIO-053
DK-ØKO-79
```

---

This is the regex, I came up with: `/[A-Z]{2}-[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŒŠŸ]{3}-\d{2,3}/`

While it works perfectly fine on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/LX8Tim/2), it doesn't work in my php-script as it returns an empty array.

```
$value = "DE-ÖKO-007";

preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}-[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŒŠŸ]{3}-\d{2,3}/', $value, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

---

My expected output would be

```
Array(
    [0] => "DE-ÖKO-007"
)
```

but I actually get

```
Array(
)
```

Am I missing something in the way `preg_match` works?

Comment: As usual with Unicode letters, use `u` modifier, `preg_match('/[A-Z]{2}-[A-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŒŠŸ]{3}-\d{2,3}/u', $value, $matches);`, see [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/p3Q7s).

Comment: oha! thank you! works perfectly fine :)